# How to add hyperlinks to enumerate items?

Tags: beamer, hyperref, enumerate

I want that each item on an enumerate list has a different hyperlink. Like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newcommand{\myitem}[2]{\item[\hyperlink{#2}{#1.\arabic{enumi}}]}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{enumerate}
         \myitem{1}{destination1} text 1
         \myitem{1}{destination2} text 2
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

the result should be:

```
1.1 text
1.2 text
...
```

However this does not wok and i get 1.0 for every number. How do I solve this?

Comment: You should add `\refstepcounter{enumi}` before `\item` in your new command `\myitem`. What is your purpose with this (creating a manual table of something...?)?

Comment: Where do the `\hyperlink`s point to? Do you have any `\hypertarget` in your document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure I understood well your problem but here is what I got:

1. You want to get hyperlinks from the number of the items pointing to some given destination elsewhere in the presentation (set via `\hypertarget{label}{text}`).
2. You want the numbers to be automatically displayed for the items.
3. (I have added this feature but I don't know if you are interested in it) You want to get the numbers of the items to be X.Y where Y is the Yth item of the current list and X is the Xth list you have in your document.

This led me to this MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\newcounter{totenum}
\setcounter{totenum}{0}
\let\Oldenumerate\enumerate
\def\enumerate{\refstepcounter{totenum}\Oldenumerate}
\newcommand{\myitem}[1]{\refstepcounter{enumi}\item[\hyperlink{#1}{\arabic{totenum}.\arabic{enumi}}]}

\begin{document}
   \begin{frame}
      \begin{enumerate}
         \myitem{destination1} text 1
         \myitem{destination2} text 2
      \end{enumerate}

      \begin{enumerate}
         \myitem{destination3} text 3
         \myitem{destination4} text 4
      \end{enumerate}
   \end{frame}

   \begin{frame}
      \hypertarget{destination1}{The first item is pointing here.}
    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

For this output (only the first frame):

[image: Output]

Comment: yes, this is it. I wasn't aware of the refstepcounter command. Sorry for the noob question

Comment: @karlkoeller Haha, I don't know, but I am used to it! ;-)